# Understanding pdf font

Tags: pdf

I have a huge list of PDF font types, here you have a part of it:

```
'/ANHCHM+Helvetica-Bold', 
'/KOFANE+AGaramondPro-Regular', 
'/AJHCPE+AdvOT863180fb', 
'/FHEENC+AdvP4C4E74', 
'/FCHDEE+AdvTimes-bi', 
'/EKIEME+Helvetica', 
'/OEPPAM+AdvOT8608a8d1+22', 
'/PNLJMH+MqxhpfAdvTT4ff65459', 
'/MLJNOB+Helvetica-Bold', 
'/FCHAFA+AdvTT689d5d16.B+20'
```

Some of those are quite readable such as 'Helvetica-Bold', or 'Helvetica', but others are completely encoded.

I need to discover from this list information like: if it's bold or not, if it's italic or not, the text size, and if it's possible a more readable font format, like 'Times New Roman', 'Arial'.

Do you know any libraries that do this, or can you tell me what is the logic of those weird names?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These are font ids in the /Resources dictionary, their name has no meaning. 
You have to look inside the font dictionary, font descriptor and possibly the actual font data (if the font is embedded) for the information you are looking for.

**bold** - There is no specific flag that tells if a font is bold or not. /BaseFont entry in the font dictionary can give you a hint, /FontWeight entry in font descriptor can also give a hint.
**italic** - /ItalicAngle entry in the font descriptor can give this information. Also the /BaseFont entry can give you a hint (if the names contains Italic or Oblique words)
**text size** - you have to parse the page content to find the size for a specific text instance.
**readable font name** - /BaseFont entry usually contains the font name. But a PDF generator application can create a custom name for a font subset so you cannot know the original font. You can further inspect the /FontFamily entry in the font descriptor or you can parse the actual font data for font name information.

Comment: What I posted is actually the BaseFont entry in the font dictionary

Comment: @RoxanaIstrate *actually the BaseFont entry* - still it's a name. The initial "XXXXXX-" is a hint that those are embedded font subsets. The part thereafter usually is the original font name. And names may be fairly arbitrary, and nobody is forced to name their font in an apropos manner, a thin font may be called "Black" or "Bold", a straight one may be called "Oblique". Interpreting those names is educated guesswork at best.

Comment: @mkl Thank you! Now i see. So using this is not reliable at all.